# Recursive thumbnail creation to different destination

Tags: shell-script, find, recursive, imagemagick, thumbnails

I wish to show my photo collection on my television. In order to do this, I need to resize the photos to fit in a 1920x1080px window (because the performance is awful when dealing with the originals).

My intended structure is:

```
/path/to/originalphotos/
/path/to/originalphotos/2016/2016-01-01 Description/DSC_1234.JPG
/path/to/originalphotos/2019/2019-12-31 Description/DSC_5678.JPG

/path/to/thumbnails/
/path/to/thumbnails/2016/2016-01-01 Description/DSC_1234_thumb.JPG
/path/to/thumbnails/2019/2019-12-31 Description/DSC_5678_thumb.JPG
```

I am trying to create a script that loops through `/path/to/originalphotos/` and creates a thumbnail (using Imagemagick's `convert` utility) of every `.JPG`-file in the corresponding subdirectory.

So far, my Bash script looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE_PATH="/path/to/originalphotos/"
DESTINATION_PATH="/path/to/thumbnails/"
find "$SOURCE_PATH" -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'echo convert \"$1\" -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080\> --write \"$DESTINATION_PATH${0%}_thumb.JPG\"' -- {} \;
```

*Note that I added `echo` to avoid saving any data.*

Can you provide any help to store the thumbnails correctly?

I have a gut feeling that I will encounter issues later on as some of my folder names contain special Danish characters (Æ, Ø, Å).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your folder names will be an issue at all. But I would suggest using shell globbing instead of `find`, just to make the syntax simpler. Something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob 
destination=/path/to/thumbnails
cd /path/to/originalphotos
for i in **/*{jpg,JPG}; do 
    dirName=${i%/*}
    file=$(basename "$i")
    fileName="${file%.*}"
    echo convert "$i" -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080\> \
        --write "$destination/${fileName}_thumb.JPG" 
done
```

That will deal with both `jpg` and `JPG` files, but note that all thumbs will end up as `.JPG`, regardless of whether they were `.jpg` or `.JPG` originally. If that's a problem, you could do something like this instead:

```
for i in **/*{jpg,JPG}; do 
    dirName=${i%/*} 
    file=$(basename "$i")
    fileName="${file%.*}" 
    ext="${file##*.}" 
    echo convert "$i" -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080\> \
        --write "$destination/${fileName}_thumb.$ext"
done
```